# adding Facebook friends to a friendlist with FB.api

Tags: javascript, facebook, post

How can I add friend(s) to a friendlist using JavaScript SDK? 
I found this example for using POST method in order to post the message to the feed:

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

However, I do not understand, how it works. Ehat is 'message' in { message: body } and how it can be adapted to this matrix "/FRIENDLIST_ID/members?members=1,2,3" (this is from FB.api examples ar https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. Make sure the key is enclosed within quotes. 'members' in this case. Though I was able to create lists, trying to add members to a created list kept throwing an exception with a message saying 'Manage_friendlists permission required' thought I had that permission. Turns out one needs the publish stream permission as well in order for this to work. This wasn't mentioned anywhere. Hope this helps.

```
FB.api('/' + friendlistID + '/members', 'post', {'members': members}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Could not save members!');
  } else {
    alert('Members added to list!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the endpoint, and the data you're sending.

The Graph Endpoint you're using is [FriendList](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/)

```
friendlist_id = 1435134523451;
FB.api('/'friendlist_id+'/members', 'post', {members:'comma,separated,ids,of,friends,to,add,to,list'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('yay!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
FB.api('/FRIENDLIST_ID/members?members=1,2,3', 'post', function(response) { … });
```

should do it.